# Struggling to reduce a summation

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find a closed expression for 
$$
\sum\limits_{t=1}^\infty (y_t)^2  
$$
where 
$$
y_t= \theta b^t cos(2\pi \rho t)
$$

I've get a pattern after expanding it but I'm not doing it well. Which would be the right approach to find this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your sum is over $n$. Should it be over $t$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\cos{2\pi \rho t} = \left( (e^{2\pi i \rho})^t+(e^{-2\pi i \rho})^t \right)/2 $. Then your sum is just
$$ \frac{\theta^2}{4} \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} b^{2t}\left( (e^{2\pi i \rho})^t+(e^{-2\pi i \rho})^t \right)^2\\
=\frac{\theta^2}{4} \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} (b^{2}e^{4\pi i \rho})^t + (b^{2}e^{-4\pi i \rho})^t + 2b^{2t} \\
 = \frac{\theta^2}{4}\left( \frac{b^{2}e^{4\pi i \rho}}{1-b^{2}e^{4\pi i \rho}} + \frac{b^2}{1-b^2} + \frac{b^{2}e^{-4\pi i \rho}}{1-b^{2}e^{-4\pi i \rho}} \right)\\
= \frac{\theta^2 b^2}{4}\left(\frac{1}{1-b^2}+ \frac{e^{4\pi i \rho}(1-b^{2}e^{-4\pi i \rho}) + e^{-4\pi i \rho}(1-b^{2}e^{4\pi i \rho})}{(1-b^{2}e^{4\pi i \rho})(1-b^{2}e^{-4\pi i \rho})} \right) \\
= \frac{\theta^2 b^2}{4}\left(\frac{1}{1-b^2}+ \frac{2(\cos{4\pi \rho}-b^2) }{1-2b^{2}\cos{4\pi \rho}+b^{4}} \right),
 $$
which probably doesn't simplify much further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me, what should I do if the expression in the cosine is multiplied by a factor 0<rho<1.